# QGIS Webmap Layers Missing

Tags: qgis, openlayers, qgis2web, orthophoto

So I am trying to create a webmap in QGIS with the qgis2web plugin that shows an Ortho (saved as GeoTIFF) created from an airplane overlaid on background satellite imagery. I tried using Leaflet originally, but it kept crashing, so I used OpenLayers instead. However, when I export the web map only the satellite imagery shows up. Interestingly the ortho shows up the preview window. Also if I only create a webmap of just the ortho is does not appear. Does anyone have any idea of why it is doing this?

Comment: I think it's a projection problem, have you tried the "match project crs" setting in the "appearance" tab? Can you upload your data somewhere and put the link here?  keep in mind that qgis2web will transform your geotif into png so the export will take some time, and the final web map will also take some time to launch if the png exceed 20mb each

Comment: I tried selecting match crs in the appearance tab and that did not work

Comment: I also tried saving both layers as one background layer using the generate xyz tiles tool and now all I get is a blank background. I have been also using the warp tool to ensure all the layers I have been working with have the same crs as the project.

Comment: Can you save your data online and put link here? I will test it